# Sum of field from left join activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, left-join

How can I get the sum of capacities.capacity ?

```
 @capacitysum = User.joins("left join capacities c on users.id = c.user_id")
.where('c.created_at = (SELECT MAX(c.created_at) FROM c WHERE c.user_id = users.id)')
.where('users.role = ?', 'consultant')
```

I tried adding a .sum('c.capacity'), .sum(:capacity) and .sum('capacities.capacity') with no success...

Answer (score 0):

Try with add a select statement :

```
@capacitysum = User.joins("left join capacities c on users.id = c.user_id")
.where('c.created_at = (SELECT MAX(c.created_at) FROM c WHERE c.user_id = users.id)')
.where('users.role = ?', 'consultant').select("sum(c.capacity)")
```

Comment: Now it does not fail but simply echoing @capacitysum gives, <ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x007fe884acbfb0

Comment: So testing a little bit more your answer seems to be a step in the right direction, altough I still get an error; column "users.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function